# Outputting JSON from Curl APi call to Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, curl

I am working on a course project in which I am required to use php to make api calls.

The Ajax call looks like this:

```
$('#btnOneRun').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCapitalSummary.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                console.log(result)
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
    }); 
});
```

The php api call looks like this:

```
<?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);



    $url='http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?formatted=true&q=london&maxRows=1&username=flightltd&style=full';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result, true);   

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];

    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

This works perfectly. I have used the same routine to make similar calls go the geonames API and had no issues doing so as they provide the name of the root object returned. In the example above, it is called geonames

`$output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];`

I am trying to use this pattern to make a call to the accuweather API. For this however, I don't have the name of the root object.

I used the routine above, changing that specific line of code to `$output['data'] = $result;` and voila, I can see where `geonames` is coming from.

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": "200",
        "name": "ok",
        "description": "success",
        "returnedIn": "120 ms"
    },
    "data": "{\"geonames\": [{\n  \"summary\": \"London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium (...)\",\n  \"elevation\": 8,\n  \"geoNameId\": 2643743,\n  \"feature\": \"city\",\n  \"lng\": -0.11832,\n  \"countryCode\": \"GB\",\n  \"rank\": 100,\n  \"thumbnailImg\": \"http://www.geonames.org/img/wikipedia/43000/thumb-42715-100.jpg\",\n  \"lang\": \"en\",\n  \"title\": \"London\",\n  \"lat\": 51.50939,\n  \"wikipediaUrl\": \"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London\"\n}]}"
}
```

At this point I thought: "Now I just need to do the same with the API call to Accuweather and I will be able to find what I need to type between the curly brackets on `$output['data'] = $decode['what_goes_here?'];` but when I tried that, the JSON return does not display an object like the one above.

The JSON returned from the accuweather API when called straight from my javascript file, or through the example in their website, looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "LocalObservationDateTime": "2022-03-10T06:47:00+00:00",
    "EpochTime": 1646894820,
    "WeatherText": "Light rain",
    "WeatherIcon": 12,
    "HasPrecipitation": true,
    "PrecipitationType": "Rain",
    "IsDayTime": true,
    "Temperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 8,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 46,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "MobileLink": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/current-weather/328328?lang=en-us",
    "Link": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/current-weather/328328?lang=en-us"
  }
]
```

I am asking for help with one of two things:

a) A way to decode that JSON object without knowing what that object name is and output that to the AJAX call, or;

b) Receive the decoded object on javascript and decode it to access its properties there.

I immensely thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON returned by the AccuWeather API?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I looked more into PHP and realized that I did not understand that the php routine was simply using bracket notation to access the properties of the decoded object: `$decode['geonames']`.

I carried on looking into it and realized that I could use `JSON.parse()` in my javascript file.

So I changed that specific line of code in the php file to `$output['data'] = $result;`

Then on my ajax call I can access the properties of the JSON returned after using calling `JSON.parse(result.data)` as shown below:

```
$('#btnOneRun').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getWeather.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
        console.log(JSON.parse(result.data))
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
    }); 
});
```

This is logged as:

```
[
    {
        "LocalObservationDateTime": "2022-03-10T08:13:00+00:00",
        "EpochTime": 1646899980,
        "WeatherText": "Mostly cloudy",
        "WeatherIcon": 6,
        "HasPrecipitation": false,
        "PrecipitationType": null,
        "IsDayTime": true,
        "Temperature": {
            "Metric": {
                "Value": 9.1,
                "Unit": "C",
                "UnitType": 17
            },
            "Imperial": {
                "Value": 48,
                "Unit": "F",
                "UnitType": 18
            }
        },
        "MobileLink": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/current-weather/328328?lang=en-us",
        "Link": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/current-weather/328328?lang=en-us"
    }
]
```

Comment: You can use an explicit `JSON.parse(result.data)` on the client, but that's bad style. If you need to do this, it means the server is sending double-encoded JSON, and *that* means the server runs sloppy code.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak. I ended up using `JSON.parse(result.data)`. After reading your comment, I looked more into PHP and realized that I did not understand that the routine was simply using bracket notation to access the properties of the decoded object: `$decode['geonames']`. Thank you for your support.